# How will configure new Relic as middleware with graphQL in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, graphql, newrelic

I'm new in this stack. please can you suggest how will do that to integrate new relic with graphQL as middleware in nodeJS.
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [graphql-middleware](https://medium.com/@rajeshkrishnakumar/how-to-monitor-express-graphql-apps-in-new-relic-718a6f5d2760) and the new relic npm package if u want to monitor
GraphQL Query resolvers as separate Web transactions

This [doc](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/install-nodejs-agent/) will help you instrument the new relic agent